# ReactiveUI WPF routing

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have registered the all the views and view models in App.xaml OnStartup method like so:

```
var model = new OnlineRegistrationsViewModel(_dataService, this);
Locator.CurrentMutable
   .RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant<IScreen>(this);            
Router.Navigate.Execute(model).Subscribe();
base.OnStartup(e);
```

The view get started as expected, but the ViewModel is null. So no data is shown as a result.

The View class is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : IViewFor<OnlineRegistrationsViewModel>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel",
            typeof(OnlineRegistrationsViewModel), typeof(MainWindow),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(disposableReg =>
        {
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
                vm => vm.OnlineRegistrationsSearchResults,
                v => v.OnlineRegistrationDataGrid.ItemsSource)
                .DisposeWith(disposableReg);
        });
    }

    public OnlineRegistrationsViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => (OnlineRegistrationsViewModel)this.GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get => ViewModel;
        set => ViewModel = (OnlineRegistrationsViewModel)value;
    }
}
```

I have looked around for examples, where they are seem to be instantiating the view model directly in the view. What did I miss? My understanding is that view model first approach should wire up the view model to the view object correctly by the ReactiveUI router.

I created a small wpf app and added the element like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:rx="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI;assembly=ReactiveUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <rx:RoutedViewHost />
</Grid>
```

It does not seem to be recognised in xaml.

Thanks.

Comment: I figured that I don't have RoutedViewHost element in Window.xaml. And according to this, it looks like it does the job of setting ViewModel property in the View. https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/4a7b6c7cb35efe4e936b6779e2ad60964894e1d0/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/windows-common/RoutedViewHost.cs And I am not able to add this to the xaml and it looks like it couldn't find the required RoutedViewHost in ReactiveUI namespace.

Comment: Have you installed the reactiveui.wpf NuGet package. You can get weird stuff like this if you haven't.

Comment: i tried adding in and it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What's your XAML look like? Are you using the RoutedViewHost? The auto view model setting requires a control like RoutedViewHost or ViewModelViewHost.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I added my sample project xaml in original post.

Comment: I figured it out. It need to be xmlns:rx="http://reactiveui.net" in xaml. :)